# Trying to write a unit test for django-rest-passwordreset, but the password seemingly will not change in the test?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the standard installation of [django-rest-passwordreset](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/). I am trying to test the password reset process. Here is my unit test:

```
    def test__password_reset_resets_password_success(self):
        testing_password = "Testing12345"
        # Generate a user and trigger the password reset
        user = self.login_basic_user()
        user.set_password(wrong_password)
        body = {"email": user.email}
        self.make_request("POST", url=self.password_reset_url, data=body)

        # Go and get the password reset email and token
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        message = mail.outbox[0]
        url, token = self.get_url_and_token(message.body)

        # Resetting the password
        body = {"password": testing_password, "token": token}
        resp = self.make_request("POST", url=self.password_change_password_url, data=body)
        self.assertEqual(resp["status"], "OK")
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(testing_password))
```

However, for some reason the check_password at the end does not return True with the new password. It only returns true with the old password. It seems that for some reason the POST is not causing the new password to be saved to the database. Why might this be?

I have tested the urls manually with the DRF interface, so I know the password resets successfully that way.

I also added the post_password_reset signal and it is triggered when running this test. It just seems that the password itself is not resetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to reload the `user` from the database.

Adding `user.refresh_from_db()` after the API call solved my problem.